# how to respond to wsdl policies using php nusoap

Tags: php, authentication, wsdl, nusoap, policy

I wish to consume a webservice described in a wsdl file. I am using php and nusoap library.

I am not sure how to correctly respond to the following policy requests:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="MyPolicies">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:TransportBinding>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                       </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                   <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                       <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:Basic256/>
                       </wsp:Policy>
                   </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                   <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Lax/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                   </sp:Layout>
                   <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
               </wsp:Policy>
           </sp:TransportBinding>
           <sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
               <wsp:Policy>
                   <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
               <wsp:Policy>
                   <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
               </wsp:Policy>
           </sp:UsernameToken>
       </wsp:Policy>
       </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
      <sp:Wss10>
         <wsp:Policy/>
     </sp:Wss10>
  </wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
```

I have been reading about WSDL policies a lot as I was looking for a solution to this, but I am still not able to figure out how exactly do I need to set my nusoap client to correctly respond to these policies. Right now I am getting this response from the web service:

```
An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
```

Any help or reading material would be much appreciated!